# Unharmed, you need it every day

Tags: riddle

I came up with this simple riddle that I think has a rather fun solution:

> Unharmed, you need it every day;
>   Decapitated, you see it and you say.

Short, sweet, and to the point. Good luck!

Comment: To those who marked this "too broad", how do you suggest I fix it?

Comment: The puzzle you have provided has many valid answers, but most of them are not the specific answer you want. It's like asking "name a colour" and telling everyone that doesn't say "fuschia" that they have the wrong answer.

Comment: Most of the answers here are ignoring at least one part of the riddle.

Comment: Thanks to all who voted to reopen - I do think most answers really missed the "see it" part of the riddle. To those who voted to close, I understand where you're coming from as well. Hopefully the right answer does seem "more right" than the other answers provided, though I acknowledge that a few answers provided do seem to fit the entire riddle, albeit some more loosely than others.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

UPDATED.  Oh for Pete's sake. *forehead smack*

Is it

> BREAD AND BUTTER

Unharmed, we need it every day,

> We need food every day.  It needn't literally be bread; it can mean food in general as "our daily bread".

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> Remove the first letters and it becomes READ AND UTTER.

Comment: This is pretty close, but not *totally* correct yet. :)

Comment: @BaileyM: Is the answer not Bread? Or has dennisdeems simply missed an explanation?

Comment: Bread is not the full answer, no.

Comment: Garlic bread maybe?  :)

Comment: arlic read, yes. Well done.

Comment: Well I believe we have a winner congrats

Comment: You need garlic bread every day???? Really? Are there a lot of vampires in your area?

Comment: Wouldn't it be read nd utter? :p

Comment: Oh, hey, this is correct. Good job. :) Our "bread and butter" is a phrase literally meaning something we need every day.

Comment: @BaileyM Google would disagree, it says that it is figurative for "a person's livelihood or main source of income, typically as earned by routine work". Also, it "literally means" bread and butter.

Comment: @MarkN oh god, did I do the "literally" thing? I hate it when people do that...still, I would describe a main source of income as something I need every day.

Comment: You also knead it. Clever.

Answer (score 16):

Might it be

> Touch?

Unharmed, you need it every day;

> Touch is one of the five senses we use everyday to obtain information and we touch a LOT of things everyday

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> If you see something painful, you instinctively say "Ouch!"

Another possible answer (going with the "see" hint):

> Eyes

Unharmed, you need it every day;

> Again with the senses motif the eyes are where we obtain the most information from the world. You can't see with an injured eye.

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> The word Yes could be used as an exclamation when you get the right answer.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I'm glad your first downvote didn't compel you to go through your plan of not posting on this 'elitist site'. :-P No hint of sarcasm though, I'm glad you're still here. :-)

Comment: Guh, I wish I didn't say that then >_>

Comment: I need your arms around me, I need to feel your touch,
I need your understanding, I need your love, So much

Comment: @Doge great answer, but you're not "seeing" ouch, 
"Decapitated, you see it and you say."
It might be it, but the "you see it" seems to point to something else.

Comment: This is an awesome answer too, but my answer does fit with "see" a bit better. Still, +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

> A head

But if you decapitate it (remove the head), you get...

> A

Which you say as you see it.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of a stretch, I feel, but is it

> Brain?

Unharmed, we need it every day,

> Undoubtedly you need it every single day, and in its unharmed state, naturally.

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> When I "decapitate" 'Brain', I remove the first letter (the head of the word?) and get 'rain'. And when it unexpectedly begins to rain, we often exclaim 'Rain!'

Comment: The rain part is a bit of a stretch, but you're thinking the correct way. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about

> Food

Unharmed, you need it every day;

> Gotta eat..

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> When you have seen food, you might have "ood" while others might have "aahd".

Comment: Not sure what deserved the downvote. I'd like to know how I should attempt to improve my answer.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but it might be due to the fact that the word is spelled ***oohed***, not ***ood***.

Answer (score 3):

> gland!

when you see

> land

you say

> land!

Comment: @baileyM am i close?

Comment: It's the right strategy, but the answer is not correct. It's a good guess though!

Comment: I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Built off of dennisdeems answer.

> Daily bread

You need it because

> without your daily bread (food) you will die. "Bring us this day our daily bread"

Decapitate it and:

> Or at least, decapitate part of it and you get your "daily read". Like a newspaper or something.

Comment: This is closer, and good intuition using more than one word. :) Still not the answer I intended, though!

Comment: Well, you certainly can't decapitate both words in there :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess:

> Sleep

Unharmed, you need it every day;

> You need sleep every day

Decapitated, you see it and you say.

> Eep! Who wants to see something decapitated?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:

> H<sub>2</sub>O

Unharmed, you need it every day

> Need water every day

Decapitated, you see it and you say

> O is the decapitated version of H<sub>2</sub>O
>  When you see something decapitated you say: O! (written: Oh!)

Answer (score 0):

Is it 'hello'? I do use it in most days and without the head 'o' it's hell, which I'd say something about upon seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it daylight?

We need the unharmed word in order for it to be "day" (not night)

Decapitate the first syllable..."day" ...and we can see because it is "light"

and we say .. "Oh say can you see..." .....how's that? :)